# SQL Server Select count > than 1

Tags: sql-server, select, asp-classic

Project: Classic ASP VBScript / SQL Server 2012

I have 2 tables, `Products` and `Categories`.

I want to build a SQL query that will return **ONLY** the categories that have **MORE THAN ONE** product.

The common key between the 2 tables is the column `Category_id` (exists in the `Products` table and also in the `Categories` table).

Comment: Are you looking for `having`? `...having count(category) > 1`?

Comment: Please send what you tried so far. e.g. did you already try grouping and the having clause mentioned by Dmitry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categories C
WHERE C.Category_id IN ( SELECT P.Category_id FROM Products P GROUP BY P.Category_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: The question explicitly states *return **ONLY** the Categories that have **MORE THAN ONE** product.*  Your answer does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @Tien Nguyen
Your code works PERFECT!
But I forgot something very important in my initially question:
In the "Products" table I have also a field named "einai_ram" . The data type of this field is "BIT".
So I want to add also in the query that the "einai_ram" field must be TRUE (checked).

Comment: You want to build a SQL query that will return ONLY the categories that have MORE THAN ONE product and einai_ram of product must be TRUE. If true then you can use this query: SELECT * 
FROM Categories C
WHERE C.Category_id IN ( SELECT P.Category_id FROM Products P WHERE P.einai_ram = TRUE GROUP BY P.Category_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: @Tien Nguyen

That’s exactly is that I want! I tried your code but I am receiving:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14' 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'TRUE'.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I'm sorry. SELECT * FROM Categories C WHERE C.Category_id IN ( SELECT P.Category_id FROM Products P WHERE P.einai_ram = 1 GROUP BY P.Category_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1). I think that it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `having` clause for this type of query, which filters your dataset *after* doing all the aggregates:

```
declare @Categories table(CategoryID int);
declare @Products table(ProdID int, CategoryID int);

insert into @Categories values(1),(2),(3);
insert into @Products values(10,1),(20,1),(30,2),(40,2),(50,3);

select c.CategoryID
        ,count(1) as ProductCount
from @Categories c
    left join @Products p
        on(c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
group by c.CategoryID
having count(1) > 1;
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------------+
| CategoryID | ProductCount |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 |            2 |
|          2 |            2 |
+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple `Group by` with `Having` as next demo:-

```
create table Products (ProductID int, name varchar(50), Category_id int )
insert into Products 
values
(1,'aaaa',1),
(2,'bbbb',1),
(3,'ccccc',2),
(4,'11111',2),
(5,'11111ccc',3)

create table Categories (Category_id int, name varchar(50))
insert into Categories 
values
(1,'Letters'),
(2,'Numbers'),
(3,'NumbersAndLetters')

-- CategoryID = 3 has only one product ..

select p.Category_id ,count(p.ProductID) CountProducts from 
Products p inner join Categories c
on p.Category_id = c.Category_id
group by p.Category_id
having count(p.ProductID) > 1
```

**Result:-**

```
Category_id CountProducts
   1              2
   2              2
```